# Create JHipster application for Java 8 instead of Java 17

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jhipster

I created an application using JHipster. By default, it created for Java 17. But I need for Java 8.
Is there any way to create application directly for Java 8 instead of Java 17?

I know that after downloading, we can change the version inside the project code. But wanted to know if there's an option to directly obtain the app for Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot requires the Java versions that JHipster uses. For example, Spring Boot 2 (used in JHipster 7) requires Java 11. JHipster 8 requires Java 17 because Spring Boot 3 requires it.

This will create an app that requires Java 11:

```
npx generator-jhipster@7 --defaults
```

You might be able to use JHipster 6. However, it's over three years old and not recommended from a security perspective.